# Problem executing regex with a shell command inside Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-os

I am trying to write a Python script to automate some tasks while the event of high inbound connections to the server.

So a portion of it is to collect all the IPv4 addresses on the server.

The command helps to list out that.

```
# ip a s eth0 | egrep -o 'inet [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | cut -d' ' -f2
198.168.1.2
198.168.1.3
198.168.1.4
```

The problem I am facing when executing the shell regex part inside the python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
ipv4_regex='[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
os_cmd = 'ip a s eth0 | egrep -o 'inet ipv4_regex' | cut -d' ' -f2'
os.system(os_cmd)
```

But the output is error:

```
# ./dos_fix.py
  File "./dos_fix.py", line 4
    os_cmd = 'ip a s eth0 | egrep -o 'inet ipv4_regex' | cut -d' ' -f2'
                                     ^
```

To see if it was due to any whitespace interrupting between the egrep and pipe, I tried to escape those quotes with backslashes, but no luck.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
ipv4_regex='[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
os_cmd = 'ip a s eth0 | egrep -o \'inet ipv4_regex\' | cut -d\' \' -f2'
os.system(os_cmd)
```

What am I missing here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes and don't escape.

In the regular expression, use a raw string: `r'contents'`.

[os.system](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.system) has some limitations. [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) is much better.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

ipv4_regex = r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
os_cmd = f"ip a s eth0 | egrep -o 'inet {ipv4_regex}' | cut -d' ' -f2"
os.system(os_cmd)
```

Comment: Hmm, would be helpful if you rewrite the code snippet correctly. That would be helpful for some other people with the same issue

Comment: I missed that you were not injecting the regex into the command!

Comment: About f-strings: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Comment: About raw strings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess you are trying to execute has no idea that `ipv4_regex` is a Python variable, or what its value might be. You are simply searching for that string literally, `i` `p` `v` `4` etc.

A much better solution anyway is to do as much of the processing as possible in Python.

```
import subprocess
import re

ipv4_regex=re.compile(r'inet [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')

for line in subprocess.run(
    ['ip', 'a', 's', 'eth0'],
    capture_output=True, text=True, 
    check=True
).stdout.split('\n'):
    m = ipv4_regex.search(line)
    if m:
        print(line.split()[1])
```

(I had to guess a bit what your script is supposed to do, since the syntax you used is invalid.)

Like the `os.system` documentation already tells you, `subprocess` is much more versatile, and generally recommended over the bare legacy `os.system`. In particular, if you want the output of the subprocess to be made available to Python, and not just displayed on the console, you *need* to use `subprocess`. It also gives you more control over the subprocess, including the ability to not use a shell when you don't need one. (See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess))

Notice the use or a "raw" string to get the actual backslashes into the regex; Python does its own backslash processing on strings in source code, so you have to double the backslashes to put in a literal backslash in a string if you don't use the `r'...'` syntax.

If your target platform is Linux, probably a better solution still is to extract the information directly in machine-readable format from the `/proc` filesystem.